# Как установить путь к 7z.dll?

Tags: c#, dll, 7z

Установлены библиотеки через nuget:
1) SevenZipSharp

Скопирована 7z.dll от 7z в \packages\ .

При добавлении ссылки на неё

> Не удаётся добавить ссылку на ...
>   Убедитесь, что файл доступен, и является допустимой сборкой или компонентом COM

Как указать к ней путь?

```
//так работает но 7z.dll используется сторонняя
//SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll");

// Синхронная упаковка
var cmpr = new SevenZipCompressor();
cmpr.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Fast;
cmpr.CompressFiles(archiveName, fileNames);
```

> Необработанное исключение типа "SevenZip.SevenZipLibraryException" в
>   SevenZipSharp.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Can not load 7-zip library or internal COM
>   error! Message: DLL file does not exist.

Comment: а в референсы добавить нельзя?

Comment: Они уже добавлены в проект,  что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: У вас две сборки с одинаковыми именами? Не понятен вопрос

Comment: при указании SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath на 7z.dll установленные через nuget `Can not load 7-zip library or internal COM error!`

При добавлении ссылки на оригинальную 7zdll от 7z ` Не удаётся добавить ссылку`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что нужно для работы с 7zip:

1. Установить Nuget-пакет SevenZipSharp.
2. Убедиться, что архитектура (x86/x64) используемой 7z.dll совместима с архитектурой вашей сборки. Если у вас 64-битная сборка, то использовать вам нужно также 64-битную версию 7z.dll.
3. Настроить копирование библиотеки 7z.dll в аутпут директорию (например, в post build событии).
4. Указать путь к ней:

   ```
   var currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
   SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(Path.Combine(currentDir, "7z.dll"));
   ```

Comment: А нельзя 7z.dll встроить в exe?

Comment: @codename0082016 смысл?